# how to locate the global variables in JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand something with JS .. 
in the function below, which is the global variable? 
can you please help me understand this?

```
(function() {
  let grade = {score: 100, status: "passing"};
  age = 45;
  var salary = 45000;
```

Comment: What variable is not defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Undeclared variables are always global.

Thus the variable *age* is the global variable.

```js
(function() {
  let grade = {score: 100, status: "passing"};
  age = 45;
  var salary = 45000;
})();
console.log(window.age);   //45
console.log(window.salary);//undefined
console.log(window.grade); //undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `age` is an *implicit global* because it's just mentioned on the left side of an assignment, and not explicitly declared with `var` or `let`.

In "strict" mode that would be an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not add var in-front of an undeclared variable, Javascript will assume it is a global variable.